# On single SVN branch to GIT migration - Not able to get all history of trunk

Tags: git, svn, github, gitlab, git-svn

We are migrating project from svn to git. In the process we only need to migrate a single branch. I have used the below command to migrate

```
git svn clone https://svn.example.com/project/branch/somebranch
```

It had cloned the branch properly, But we are getting history from the creation of the branch. How can we get history from the start of the project. From svn while browsing the branch we can able to see all history.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and see if **[subgit import](http://www.subgit.com/remote-book.html#7)** (as an alternative to [`git svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn)) would not be able to get you the full history for that imported branch.

[SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/) has a free offer for import, and it generally is more robust than [`git svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn): it might better handle that branch import.

Or you could even import the full repo (again with `subgit`), and then delete (with [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)) what you don't need in the Git repo.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked with svn2git gem -- https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git

using below command it worked, getting all history now...

**svn2git https://svn.example.com/project/branch/somebranch --rootistrunk --authors /path/to/file/authors.txt --username <>**

Thanks